# How is this syntax possible?

Tags: javascript, function, new-operator

#### Confusion:

I was looking at the tc39 proposal for `async do {}` which is instead of doing `(async()=>{})`. I was trying to see if I could replicate it somehow by playing around with keywords. Here, I found something odd:

```js
new function() {
    console.log(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0])
}
//This works but returns {}
```

The code above executes normally, but will always return `{}`. Of course, one could always use the void operator:

```js
void new function() {
    console.log(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0])
}
//This works and returns undefined
```

#### Questions:

- How does this `new function() {}` work?
- Why does this code self-invoke *(similar to `(function(){})()`)*?
- Why does an attempt at using this with the keyword `async` throw an error?

Comment: Well, what does `new Klass` usually do when `Klass` is defined as `function Klass() {}`? It calls that function. You’ve just inlined an anonymous function.

Comment: The [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) invokes a constructor. A function expression is a valid constructor. So it get's invoked. That answers first and second questions. Constructors cannot be asynchronous is the answer to the third.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, thanks for the good explanation :)

Comment: The `new function` syntax, whichever way you declare it, is an object constructor. It will immediately construct and return an object. Since your code doesn't really contain object constructor instructions, it creates and returns an empty object. The 'new' cannot be used against `async` instruction, because it's not a constructor.
1. it works because it is a function which can be used as a custom object constructor.
2. it has to evaluate it before it creates your custom object.
3. `async` is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered in the comments, but I want to make an accepted answer so this question can be considered "answered". The keyword `new` in javascript creates a new instance of a function/class. A function, **NOT** an async function, is an instance of a function/class allowing for it to be created and run.

---

This code creates the same product --

```js
function example() {
    console.log('hello');
    return {
        process: 'finished'
    }
};
new example;
```

-- as this code.

```js
new function() {
    console.log('hello');
    return {
        process: 'finished'
    }
};
```

Because of the way it is constructed, an object has to be returned. This makes it different from an IIFE. If an objects is not returned, the product will be a blank `{}`. The reason why the syntax `new async function() {}` is incorrect is the same as `class { async constructor() {} }`. Constructors require an immediate return value, which forces them to be synchronous.